# When trying to get images from storage, I get the error "Field 'downloadUrl' has not been initialized"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

```
      late File uploadFile;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String downloadUrl;

  void gallery() async {
    var getDoc = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      uploadFile = File(getDoc!.path);
    });

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("profilePics")
        .child(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .child("profilePic.png");

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(uploadFile);
    String url = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      downloadUrl = url;
    });

     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    gallery();
                  },
                  child: Text('Upload'),
                ),
                Image.network(downloadUrl),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Before adding the `Image.network(downloadUrl`) part in the code, I was able to select a photo from the gallery and display it in storage. But when I try to display the image loaded in the storage in the application with the `Image.network(downloadUrl)` code, I get the error "Field 'downloadUrl' has not been initialized". `late String downloadUrl;` part, `String? downloadUrl;` I changed it to. But this time I get the error "Null check operator used on a null value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `Image.network()` requires a String in, that isn't null, and your variable `downloadUrl` is null until your async method `gallery()` has completed.

Several things could fix this, one way is using a FutureBuilder, perhaps google and read about that. Another way is to do the following edits:

Change

```
late String downloadUrl;
...
Image.network(downloadUrl)
```

to

```
String? downloadUrl;
...
downloadUrl != null ? Image.network(downloadUrl) : CircularProgressIndicator()
```